# Retrieve date, month, year from a date in php

Tags: php

I have this piece of code which gets me a field from the database:

```
$end_date=$row1['end_date'];
```

If i print it it gives me something like: 25-09-2012
What i need is to get the month value, the year and date.
something like:

```
$month=09;
$day=25;
$year=2012;
```

How can i do that?
thanks!

Comment: Look at strtodate and date functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function like this :

```
// store a string containing "25-09-2012"
$end_date = $row1['end_date'];

// split "25-09-2012" into an array of three elements
$thedate = explode("-", $end_date);

// retrieve the values
$month = $thedate[0]; // 25
$day = $thedate[1]; // 09
$year = $thedate[2]; // 2012
```

Comment: Thank you very much, nice and clean :)
i'm accepting your question in a few minutes :)

Comment: Can i ask you something please?
i need that this numbers i extracted to be without 0, i mean if the month is 01, i need it 1, how can i do that?

Comment: You have to convert the string to an integer, for that you can simply use the [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function.

Answer (score 5):

Using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime($row1['end_date']);
$year = $date -> format('Y');
$month = $date -> format('m');
$day = $date -> format('d');
```

If your timestamps are all like the one provided, keep it simple:

```
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $row1['end_date']);
```

Answer (score 1):

try 
`[month('end_date')]`
`[day('end_date')]`
`[year('end_date')]`

Or use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and use - as the delimiter

Comment: in mysql, it works for date fields, it pulls the month, so was wondering it may work in this situation aswell. If not ave advised to use explode

Answer (score 1):

Take a peak at this helpful tutorial describing various formatting methods and useful date functions in PHP:

[Date/Time Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[Date Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = getdate(strtotime($row1['end_date']));
echo $values['mon']; //month
echo $values['mday']; //day
echo $values['year']; //year
```

Answer (score 1):

A. You can use `DateTime`

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$row1['end_date']);
$month = $date->format("m");
$day = $date->format("d");
$year = $date->format("Y");
```

B. Using `strtotime`

```
$date = strtotime($row1['end_date']);
$month = date("m", $date);
$day = date("d", $date);
$year = date("Y", $date);
```

C. You can just `sscanf` scan through the string

```
$date = sscanf($row1['end_date'], "%d-%d-%d");
$month = $date[0] ;
$day =  $date[1] ;
$year =  $date[2] ;
```

D. Another method is using `list` & `explode`

```
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $row1['end_date']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it on a single line and format it however you would like.  (Dec, December, 12) and so on with date().

```
list($month, $day, $year) = explode('-', date('m-d-Y', strtotime($row1['end_date'])));
```